# Trying to display NONE when there is no mode in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to figure the mode of a data set, while displaying "NONE" if there is no mode. I am currently using Gregor's function as commented below.

examples:

{1,1,2,2,3} 
Expected results `1 2`**(success)**

{NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,3,3} 
Expected results `NA 1`**(success)**

{1,2,3,4,5}
Expected result `NONE` **(success)**

{1,1,1,1,1}
Expected result `1` **(fail)**

EDIT: I am trying out with if...and functions, as I realize there seems to be some logical problems. But I can't seem to crack it

```
smode<-function(x,...) {
ux <- unique(x)
tx <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
if(((unique(x)>=2)&(length(unique(tx)) == 1)) {

    return("NONE")
}
max_tx <- tx == max(tx)
return(ux[max_tx])
}
```

Right now, {1,1,1,1,1,1} or any other alike just displays `NONE`
Just checked again, and {1,1,1,2,2,2} displays `NONE` too instead of `1 2`

I'm assuming it will be the same for more similiar things.

EDIT: I DID IT

```
function(x,...) {
ux <- unique(x)
tx <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
if(sum(tx)/length(tx) == 1) {

    return("NONE")
}
max_tx <- tx == max(tx)
return(ux[max_tx])
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe `sort()` the table and use an `if()` statement to check that the maximum value is unique...?

Comment: You seem possibly hung up on the case where all values occur the same number of times, but what output would you want for, e.g., `a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)`? There isn't a unique mode because `1` and `2` are tied, but `3` only occurs once. Would you want `1, 2` or `"NONE"` as a result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

Comment: @Gregor , I would want
    1,2 then. None only occurs when all of them occurred equally.

Comment: Well, in that case I would suggest you check the number of unique values in `smode`. The functions `length()` and `unique()` should help you out. I bet you can figure it out from there.

Comment: Your edits are nice to see, but you removed all the description of your problem. It would still be nice to know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tx <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  if(length(unique(tx)) == 1) {
    message("None")
    return(NA)
  }
  max_tx <- tx == max(tx)
  return(ux[max_tx])
}

Mode(1:5)
# None
# [1] NA
Mode(c(1, 1, 2, 3))
# [1] 1
Mode(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3))
# [1] 1 2
Mode(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
# None
# [1] NA
```

It's a slight modification of Ken William's `Mode` function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/903061).

Comment: Many thanks! What is the logic behind 
    `if(length(unique(tx)) == 1)`  though?

Comment: Think about it. Try some examples. I'm sure you can work it out. My `tx` is equivalent to `smode` in your original attempt.

Comment: Is the result suppose to show "None" above the df and not actually "None" in the cell?

Comment: @Kristine Generally, I think functions should be type-consistent in that if they usually return a number then they should always return a number (or at least something of class `numeric`). Since `"NONE"` can't be numeric I had the function print `"None"` as a message and return an `NA` value if there is no mode.

Comment: Oh yes! I missed that. Thank you.